# How to detect that narrator tool is running?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, screen-readers, narrator

I have a custom control. i like to provide the support for System screen reading support. Is there any logic to find that the narrator or coded UI tool is enabled in our machine.??

Answer (score 1):

You can use namespace `Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers` and this method:

```
var isNarratorStarted = AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.AutomationFocusChanged);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. But in Windows 10 machine has default support for screen reading so that each and every time the OnAutomationPeer called that means each time peers created.So far you suggestion always returns true  How to skip this. My goal is to detect that the third party screen reader tool or narrator is enabled in our machine. Because we have proceed further action based upon that

Comment: @Bala Third-party readers can be detected via SPI_GETSCREENREADER: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ProgrammaticallyDetectingScreenReaders.aspx

Comment: @daserge Is there a UWP way to do this?

Comment: @ChrisLeyva doesn't the Przemek' solution work for you?

Comment: @daserge No, it doesn't. When I get back on that project, I can try again to let you know exactly the issue I ran into. But one thing is that it would be great to be able to differentiate between Narrator/JAWS and Screen Magnifier, if possible.

Comment: I don't know why but starting with 1809 Update `AutomationEvents.AutomationFocusChanged` doesn't work anymore for system Narrator state determination, but `AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged` does work instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar case but when working with UWP app and I solved it that way. Maybe you can take something from here:

```
private bool isAutomationPeerCreated = false;

private bool IsAutomationPeerAttached => this.isAutomationPeerCreated || AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.PropertyChanged);

//triggered everytime you run narrator or any other screen reading software that is based on accessing automation properties
protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
{
    if(!this.IsAutomationPeerAttached)
    {
        this.isAutomationPeerCreated = true;
        this.OUR_LOGIC_BASED_ON_ATTACHED_NARRATOR();
    }
    return null;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    this.isAutomationPeerCreated = false;
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if(IsAutomationPeerAttached)
    {
        this.OUR_LOGIC_BASED_ON_ATTACHED_NARRATOR();       
    }
}

private void OUR_LOGIC_BASED_ON_ATTACHED_NARRATOR()
{
    //DO STH.
}
```