# How to check the accessibility tools is running in XForms UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I  need to check the accessibility tool (Narrator) is running in the windows platform .I have already tried with the following

1 one is not working and 2 one is also i have tried and it always showing the false while getting system parameters .
1.

`AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.AutomationFocusChanged);`

2.

```
[DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern long SystemParametersInfo(long uAction, int lpvParam, ref bool uParam, int fuWinIni);



public static bool IsScreenReaderRunning()
{
    long SPI_GETSCREENREADER = 70L;
    bool bScreenReader = false;
    long retVal;

    retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENREADER, 0, ref bScreenReader, 0);

    //uint iParam = 0;
    //uint iUpdate = 0;
    //bool result = false;
    //bool bReturn = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENREADER, iParam, &bScreenReader, iUpdate);
    return bScreenReader;
}

public static void ScreenReaderOn()
{
    long SPI_GETSCREENREADER = 71L;
    bool bScreenReader = true;
    long retVal;

    retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENREADER, 0, ref bScreenReader, 0);
}

public static void ScreenReaderOff()
{
    long SPI_GETSCREENREADER = 71L;
    bool bScreenReader = false;
    long retVal;

    retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENREADER, 0, ref bScreenReader, 0);
}
```

Comment: I find this case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275649/how-to-detect-that-narrator-tool-is-running and daserge suggest you can try to use **AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged**

Comment: @CherryBu I have already tried this but not works